Ways to achieve multiple cuts
I am still new to Blender and have been a user of Max and Maya. I am trying to create the following:

"When I used to do this, I would create the shapes and then be able to use snapping to cut the object, but snapping only works on the current object.
How can I achieve this with dimensional accuracy?

I'm not sure what snapping has to do with it? I'd create a Boolean cutter the size of one of the holes with a Cube and then add two Array modifiers to it to create the correct spacing between the holes. - Answer on its way...

Create loopcuts (Ctrl R) and remove the faces to create the holes?

You could use a cube and give it a couple of array modifiers to create the array, then use it with a boolean modifier to cut the wall.

For something square like this you could also just inset the face, subdivide it with a bunch of loop cuts and then inset the faces individually (Press 'i' twice) before extruding them in.
This leave quad geometry from the beginning but it's not as easy to adjust afterwards if you want to change dimensions. You'd need to know the exact size of the square holes, the space between them and the number of rows and columns to make the initial inset face the correct size


You beat me to it! :^) Use the X and Z Relative Offset settings on the two modifiers to adjust the spacing.
